# Trouble with Flex Desktop accessing XML file with namespace elements

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, e4x

I have an XML file (actually an epub contentes.opf file) partially shown as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
 <package xmlns="http://www.idpf.org/2007/opf" unique-identifier="bookid" version="2.0">  
 <metadata xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">
   <meta name="generator" content="Adobe InDesign 9.0" />
   <meta name="cover" content="x22305.png" />
   <dc:title>My Title</dc:title>
   <dc:creator>The Author</dc:creator>
etc
```

I read the file as:

```
str = XML(fileStream.readUTFBytes(fileStream.bytesAvailable));
var xmlList:XMLList = XMLList (str);
```

My xmlList trace

```
trace(xmlList);
```

now shows (seems to have added a default namespcae - not too bothered by this):

```
<aaa:package unique-identifier="bookid" version="2.0" xmlns:aaa="http://www.idpf.org/2007/opf">
  <aaa:metadata xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">
    <aaa:meta name="generator" content="Adobe InDesign 9.0"/>
    <aaa:meta name="cover" content="x22305.png"/>
    <dc:title>My Title</dc:title>
    <dc:creator>The Author</dc:creator>
```

How can I access an element from the xmlList (say title)?

Tried quite a few variation, so this is driving me a bit nuts and help would be appreciated.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to help from a chap in a flex group, the solution was (for those who have a similar question):

```
    private function contentsOpf():void
    {

        var contentsOpfFile:File   = new File(destDir.nativePath + File.separator +  "OEBPS" + File.separator + "content.opf");
        var fileStream:FileStream = new FileStream();
        fileStream.open(contentsOpfFile, FileMode.READ);

        var ns: Namespace = new Namespace("","http://www.idpf.org/2007/opf")
        var nsdc: Namespace = new Namespace("dc", "http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/")   ;

        var packageXml: XML = XML(fileStream.readUTFBytes(fileStream.bytesAvailable));

        packageXml.addNamespace(ns);
        var metadataXml: XMLList = packageXml.ns::metadata;
        metadataXml.addNamespace(nsdc);

        var titleXml: XMLList = metadataXml.nsdc::title;

        trace(packageXml.toString());
        trace(titleXml.toString());
    }
```

Phil